# In Place HeapSort

Tags: c++, heapsort

I am tasked to create sort a string by ascending or descending value essentially so I can solve the rest of the issue. I chose descending and it just about works on all outputs. I can't use any extra memory and it must run in O(n log n) so I know i should use a heapsort in place. I know how to heapsort using O(n) extra memory but in place gives me trouble. My issue is the first character in my string never gets sorted.  Everything else is sorted and I understand why it doesn't sort, I'm having trouble figuring out the solution.

To HeapSort in place with my understanding:

1) Swap the item in the bottom of the heap("last element in string") to the root

2) Than use fixDown to trickle that character downwards, by comparing against the children

The first character doesn't get sorted because once I swap it with the last element, I treat it as if it's sorted.

My fist proposed solution was to just replace the first character of the string with the minimum character of the string so when I make that initial swap, it's then sorted. This brought up more problems.

My second proposed solution was to call fixDown(s,s.size()-1,0). This way we trickle down the top element every time using the entire string but this got me farther from the solution.

Thanks for any help, I really want to learn how to fix this and I've been trying many different things before I asked on here.

```
void count_chars(string s){

for(unsigned int i=s.size()-1;i>0;--i){
    swap(s.at(i),s.at(0));
    fixDown(s,i-1,0);
}
cout<<s<<endl;
}

static void fixDown(string &s,int size,int k){

while(2*k+1<=size){
    int j=2*k+1;
    if(j<size && s.at(j) > s.at(j+1))
        ++j;
    if(s.at(k)<=s.at(j))
        break;
    swap(s.at(k),s.at(j));
    k=j;
}
```

Comment: Edit: much better description than the one I had [can be found here](http://crackprogramming.blogspot.com/2012/11/heap-sort-c-implementation.html)

Comment: So are you suggesting I trickle the value(first time will be [N-1]) upwards (heap up) by comparing to its parents?

Comment: Thats more or less the jist of it, yes. For once, a pretty nice algorithm for binary heap building is [on Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap). The idea is once the heap has been initially built you repeatedly swap the lead node to the end (building backwards), then heap down with the new root. As soon as it finds a home, repeat. I'm not tremendously elegant at describing it, but its a fairly straight up algorithm once you stare at it long enough.

Comment: Rewording WhozCraig's comment, you're missing an initial heapify step which places nodes / elements in heap order, including putting the largest value at s.at(0). After this swapping s.at(0) with s.at(end) will put the largest value at the end. Then re-heapify steps are done on a decreasing size heap until the array is sorted. Both the links in the comments explain this initial heapify step.

Comment: And its important to note once the heap is initially created, each time you swap the `[0]` node to a decreasing slot index on the other end, only the new value swapped into `[0]` needs to be pushed *down* the heap (always swapping with the *larger* of its two children if *either* is greater than the parent) until no swap is required. Once that happens you once again have a proper heap, but now one-less-element long (the one that was swapped away. IOW, a full make-heap is required *once*. After that each swap is a single element push-down until a home is found. Repeat until done.

Comment: [See it live](http://ideone.com/Ec9tdl). I encourage you to experiment with different lengths and content.